# BigQuery - Converting a mixed fraction to a decimal

Tags: google-bigquery, decimal, fractions

How to convert mixed fraction like this one '1 1/2' to a float value (1.5) using Standard SQL of BigQuery?

With few special case examples: 1, 1/2, 1 1 /2, 1 1/ 2, 1 1/2 , 1 1/2 IN, 1\t1/2 .

A large number of rows (>10M), reasonably small number of fraction variations (>.5K).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below example for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION mix_to_float(str STRING) AS ((
  SELECT 
    IFNULL(SAFE_CAST(arr[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] AS INT64), 0) +
    CAST(SPLIT(arr[SAFE_OFFSET(0)], '/')[OFFSET(0)] AS INT64) / 
    CAST(SPLIT(arr[SAFE_OFFSET(0)], '/')[OFFSET(1)] AS INT64) 
  FROM (SELECT ARRAY_REVERSE(SPLIT(str, ' ')) arr)
));
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '1 1/2' mix UNION ALL
  SELECT '8/3'
)
SELECT mix, mix_to_float(mix) as_decimal
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

result would be

```
Row     mix         as_decimal   
1       1 1/2       1.5  
2       8/3         2.6666666666666665
```

Above assumes that there is at least fraction part in the string.
Just quick option  - most likely can be optimized further :o)

Comment: Mikhail, thank you for the solution. Added some special cases variations in the question. Please find an edited equation that it is working in more complex cases:
```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION mix_to_float(str STRING) AS ((
  SELECT
    IFNULL(SAFE_CAST(TRIM(arr[SAFE_OFFSET(1)]) AS INT64), 0) 
    +
    SAFE_CAST(SPLIT(arr[SAFE_OFFSET(0)], '/')[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] AS INT64) / 
    IFNULL(SAFE_CAST(SPLIT(arr[SAFE_OFFSET(0)], '/')[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] AS INT64), 1)
  FROM (SELECT ARRAY_REVERSE(SPLIT(TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(RTRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(str, r"\s+", " "), " IN"), " /", "/")), " ")) arr)
));
```

Comment: Mikhail, what kind of optimizations you see possible. In my example, I have multi-millions of rows with less than 1000 unique mixed 'categories'. Is BigQuery applying the function to all the rows or is doing it smartly on each occurrence of the mixed values only?

Comment: as it is in answer's example - SQL UDF will be applied to every row - and somehow I feel it should not be an issue for multi-millions rows (that's not really too big for BigQuery). But still - you can try to optimize by first "extracting" those distinct values and then apply conversion from mix to float and then join back to original table - but I am not sure if this will be more performant - you need to test - so you will see what will play better for your case

Answer (score 0):

Ok - I am just looking at Google's BigQuery but it looks fairly easy to do. The first question is "Are your numbers always separated by spaces?". Example: "1 1/2". If so - use the SPLIT command to break this up into two numbers. (ie: "1" and "1/2"). Then you use split on the second part. (So SPLIT(array[1], "/").) Then all you have to do is to divide the first part of the second array by the second part and then add it to the first part of the first array. I have not programmed this language but it seems it should be very simple to do.  Look at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/array_functions for all of the commands of BigQuery. :-)

Comment: Mark, I added more exotic mixed decimal variations.

Comment: In that case - you would have to first still split it in to separate areas. I would create a variable to hold it. Then remove bad items like the "1 1 /2", you first strip out any excess spaces (most likely to use TRIM). Then look for the slash in the third area. Then, just in case you have "1 1/2in" (no spaces), you look for ascii letters (ie: a-zA-Z) and split that out, and then do the regular problems. Now, if you want to be able to hand such things as "m cm dm l km ft in yd" and all of that kind of thing - you will have a rather large IF-THEN command. (Not enough room for more.)